Azure Load Testing : Jmeter upload pdf file scenario
I have a scenario where I need to upload a pdf file using JMeter, and run the test in Azure Load Testing. Script is working fine when run in local, but I am unable to find how to attach the file in Azure Load Testing. Any suggestions are appriciated.
Tried solutions : I have tried attaching the file in at same place where script is uploaded , p2_performance_upload is jmx file and other are attachment used in script.


Giving ${working_dir} in path

I think you should leave only the ${file_to_upload} bit, like as in Update your JMeter script to read CSV data as you can see only filename is being used, without any prefixes or extra amendments to the file path.

More information: JMeter Performance Testing: JMeter Download & Upload Scenarios
